# onBlur don't work in text input react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im trying to detect when user click outside the input, but feel like it only work with onFocus but it onBlur don't do anything, here is the simple code

```
/* eslint-disable react-native/no-inline-styles */
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  TextInput,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
} from 'react-native';

const TextInputTest = () => {
  const [isBorder, setBorder] = useState(false);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <View style={{borderWidth: isBorder ? 1 : 0}}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="sometext"
          onFocus={() => setBorder(!isBorder)}
          onBlur={() => setBorder(!isBorder)}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
export default TextInputTest;
```

I can only see the border turn black and it never blank again, what happen, please help, thank you a lots

[image]

Answer (score 3):

onBlur event will be triggered when you focus out your TextInput. In this case, you have only one TextInput and you cant focus out to somewhere else as an action. Try to have 2 TextInput instead or define some actions such as an button then when you click on another TextInput or Button, onBlur will be called.

Comment: This is not solution to problem, this is a work around. When I need just 1 input, why will I add 2 ? Do you have any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to wrap your `<TextInput />` in a `<TouchableWithoutFeedback />` element and add an onPress handler for that `<TouchableWithoutFeedback />`

Here is [a snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@radugcimpian/detect-tap-outside-input) as example